# Get coordinates from Map to main Activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm doing a geocoding app. This app contains a main Activity with one button to start Google Maps API (fragment), and 2 textviews where must be shown latitude and longitude coordinates.

When I start the map, I must be able to long click on any point, and the coordinates of this point must be returned to the main Activity and appear on the Textviews.

This is the code of GoogleMapsFragments where I get touched point's position:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
//...

    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
            mLatLng = arg0;
            ReturnMapData(mLatLng);
        }
    });
}

public void ReturnMapData(LatLng arg) {
    mCodingActivity.GetLocationFromMap(mLatLng);
}
```

The method GetLocationFromMap belongs to the main Activity. Maybe here is the fail, I don't know If this is the best way to do it.

Anyway, this method in the main Activity has this looking:

```
public void GetLocationFromMap(LatLng arg0) {
    String latitud = String.valueOf(arg0.latitude);
    String longitud = String.valueOf(arg0.longitude);
    txtLatitude.setText(latitud);
    txtLongitude.setText(longitud);
}
```

But I'm getting the next error on this line `txtLatitude.setText(latitud);`

This is what appears on LogCat: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

**UPDATE - LogCat added**

```
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at com.final.reversegeocoding.GeocodingActivity.GetLocationFromMap(GeocodingActivity.java:231)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at com.final.reversegeocoding.GoogleMapsFragment.ReturnMapData(GoogleMapsFragment.java:84)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at com.final.reversegeocoding.GoogleMapsFragment$1.onMapLongClick(GoogleMapsFragment.java:70)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$7.onMapLongClick(Unknown Source)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.j$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:347)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at ecp.a(SourceFile:93)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at maps.ae.j.a(Unknown Source)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at maps.ao.an.c(Unknown Source)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at maps.ao.bc.onLongPress(Unknown Source)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at maps.br.g.onLongPress(Unknown Source)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at maps.br.h.c(Unknown Source)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at maps.br.i.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-05 13:24:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(8907):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE 2 -- How I define textlatitude:**

```
private EditText txtLatitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...

    txtLatitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.latitude_edit);
```

**UPDATE 3 -- How I call the MAP Fragment**

```
View mapFrame = findViewById(R.id.map_fragment);
            mDualPane = mapFrame != null && mapFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

            if (mDualPane){
                Fragment mapFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
                GoogleMapsFragment mapsFragment = new GoogleMapsFragment();

                if (mapFrag == null) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.add(R.id.map_fragment, mapsFragment).commit();
                }else {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.map_fragment, mapsFragment).commit();
                }
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(GeocodingActivity.this, GoogleMapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

If is a Smartphone (sinlgePane), that is the one I'm testing now, I call GoogleMapsActivity which has the next code. This Activity is just a transition Activity to call the fragment.

```
public class GoogleMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMapsFragment mapsFragment = new GoogleMapsFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, mapsFragment).commit();
}
```

**UPDATE 4 -- ReturnMapData method updated**

```
public void ReturnMapData(LatLng arg) {

    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("maps_location", arg);
    intent.putExtra("bundle", args);
    getActivity().setResult(getActivity().RESULT_OK, intent);


    View mapFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.map_fragment);
    mDualPane = mapFrame != null && mapFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

    if (!mDualPane){
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 5 -**

Modified code to use onActivityResult to get data back from MapFragment but still having some issue when getting this data. This is the way I do:

Call MapsFrament from activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(GeocodingActivity.this, GoogleMapsActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_MAP_LOCATION);
```

Send result back to main activity:

```
public void ReturnMapData(LatLng arg) {
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("maps_location", arg);
    intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
    getActivity().setResult(getActivity().RESULT_OK, intent);
}
```

Get the result on the main activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_MAP_LOCATION) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bundle bundle = data.getBundleExtra("bundle");
            LatLng coordinates = bundle.getParcelable("maps_location");
            mLocation.setLatitude(coordinates.latitude);
            mLocation.setLongitude(coordinates.longitude);
            showLocation(mLocation);
    }
}
```

But, this is what I got on the LogCat:

```
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.uax_final.reversegeocoding/.GoogleMapsActivity (has extras) }} to activity {com.uax_final.reversegeocoding/com.uax_final.reversegeocoding.GeocodingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3500)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3543)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:159)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at com.uax_final.reversegeocoding.GeocodingActivity.onActivityResult(GeocodingActivity.java:232)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3496)
```

Comment: U make sure that u get location into your `GetLocationFromMap(LatLng arg0)`

Comment: @M D Using the debugger I've seen that I get the coordinates correctly, the app crashes when making the `.setText()`. Have to say that `textLatitude` isn't a Textview, it is an EditText. Maybe the edittext has any char limit?

Comment: try this way: `txtLatitude.setText(latitud.tostring()) and txtLongitude.setText(longitud.tostring())`

Comment: @M D Nop, continues with the same error. Maybe I have to use other method to pass the data from the fragment to the activity? I don't know what to do, because as said, the debugger shows coordinate values  in the `latitud` and `longitud` strings

Comment: @M D I added the logcat

Comment: Have you defined `txtLatitude`? Maybe `txtLatitude` is null

Comment: @nikmin there is the update with how I define that.

Comment: put GetLocationFromMap in static mode

Comment: It is ok how you define it, but can you check in your `GetLocationFromMap` method if it is null? Maybe you are doing something wrong

Comment: @nikmin in `GetLocationFromMap(LatLng arg0)` the `Latitud` and `Longitud` strings have correct coordinate values. In debugger i see, `txtLatitude` and `txtLongitude` are null before doing setText(), but when I arrive to this line, crashes

Comment: @Tsunaze even If I put the method in static mode, it is doing right the job now, I mean, I'm getting the LatLng value correctly, the issue is when doing the setText call to put the value in the edtitext

Comment: Well they should not be null, here is your problem. You are messing something up.

Comment: @nikmin and what value should they have? I use 2 methods to get the location coordinates and set into the edittext. The first is using the getLastKnownLocation(), and this way it does right. And the second one, using the map. Maybe in this case, where i go to another activity and then come back to the main activity, in this process I must set something that I'm forgetting?

Comment: @masmic_87 Do you show the map fragment in new activity or in the same? Can you post the code how you show the fragment?

Comment: @nikmin I show it in a new activity. i edited the post. I think that this will be the cause, but... how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

txtLatitude is null (easily visible in the stacktrace).

Either your

```
txtLatitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.latitude_edit);
```

didn't work or you overwrote the txtLatitude with null sometime before GetLocationFromMap.

Try this to check:

```
txtLatitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.latitude_edit);
System.err.println("txtLatitude exists: "+(txtLatitude!=null));
```

You should see the output in Logcat.

If it is null try recompiling the project (clean build). Sometimes the IDE get's stuck and doesn't compile new classes correctly. If that doesn't work, maybe findViewById(R.id.latitude_edit) doesn't return an EditText that then get's lost while casting. You can check that using this:

```
System.err.println("latitude_edit is EditText: "+(findViewById(R.id.latitude_edit) instanceof EditText);
```

If it is actually not null you will have to check every assignment to txtLatitude in your whole program to see if you accidentally set it to null somewhere (most IDEs have a "find usages"-function or similar that helps a lot with stuff like that).

EDIT:
According to your comments the problem lies in your Activity-structure.
You said you have two activities, ActivityA that contains the EditTexts and ActivityB that contains the map.
Android usually only has one Activity open at a time. The others are not "alive". So if you have ActivityB open and want to edit stuff in ActivityA that might not work.
What you can use though is this:

-Start the activity with startActivityForResult instead of startActivity:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode); //requestCode is any unique number>0 you want.
```

-Implement an onActivityResult-method in ActivityA

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == x) { //x is the requestCode you chose above
     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
         String latitude=data.getStringExtra("latitude");
         String longitude=data.getStringExtra("longitude");
     } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
         //ActivityB was closed before you put any results
     }
  }
}
```

-Do something like this with your ReturnMapData-Method:

```
public void ReturnMapData(LatLng arg) {
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    intent.putExtra("latitude", String.valueOf(arg.latitude));
    intent.putExtra("longitude", String.valueOf(arg.longitude));
    this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
}
```

Comment: I think that this problem has something to do with that I call another activity to show the Map, and then, I call back from the Map to the main Activity's method this way: `mCodingActivity.GetLocationFromMap(mLatLng);` I use other ways to set the coordinates in the edittext and all of them work. The one that doesn't work is this with the map. So, maybe the way I'm passing the coordinates from the map back to the main Activity is doing the edittexts not to be initialiced

Comment: So you have Activity A that contains the EditTexts and Activity B that contains the map.
From A you open B to show the Map and while having B open you pass the data back to A, is that what you do?
If you don't do anything else in Activity B, better open B with startActivityForResult() and pass the coordinates back with ActivityB.setResult().
If you want to add other stuff, use an object to store all the data you want to put into the result and return that then.
I will put that into the answer.

Comment: I'l try that, but really what I'm doing is. 1) If it is a tablet, it will open the MapFragment on the space at the right side og the activity(using framelayout in the XML). 2) If it is a Smartphone, I can't do an intent to open a fragment, so, I start MapActivity wich just replaces the view of this with the MapGFragment (the code is on de post). So, my doubt is, if I start the activity using startActivityForResult, will do the job even if I have that structure?. And to answer you, yes, I open the Map and then when I pass data to main, i finish it

Comment: If you close the activity as soon as there is data that should still work.
Otherwise you can do a little workaround: you do it the way you did it now (which should work on a tablet where both activities are active) and just catch any Null-Pointer-Exceptions and do it with startActivityForResult() which should work for smartphones.

Comment: Ok, i'm doing it that way, just one last thing: in the `ReturnMapData(LatLng arg){` instead of passing separately latitude an logitud values, i would like to pass the `LatLng` object. For this, and using what you have posted, I edited this method the way I updated on the OP. But, i would like you to have a look if it is OK, and, to modify the `onActivityResult` method to get the Extra because I don't know how to get it using bundle.

Comment: Jup, that should work. On the other side you just get it out using Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle"); LatLng position = (LatLng) bundle.getParcelable("maps_location");

Comment: Well, done it that way, but I'm having some another issue. I posted last update with the code I use to do the data passing and the LogCat. I think that it has something to do with that i use the structure: `Main Activity -> MapsActivity -> MapsFragment` and to come back I do `MapsFragment -> Main Activity`

Comment: This issue differs a bit from this post's original question, so i've opened a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598283/get-data-between-activity-and-fragment Please, have a look here, i think i almost got it and I would appreciate your help.