# Get data between Activity and fragment with googleMaps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-intent, android-fragments

**INTRODUCTION**

Well, I have a Main Activity which has:

- 1 button that starts GoogleMaps API
- 2 Edittext to show Latitude and Longitude coordinates

I mannage the use of a smartphone or tablet, so I'm using fragment for the Map. When I use a tablet, it shows the map at the right side of the Main Acitivity (I use framelayout on XML file), and when I use a smartphone, it throws an intent to show a new activity with the Map.

But, as MapsFragment isn't an activity, I can't call it with an intent, for what I've created an intermediate activity.

The structure is this: `MainActivity(GeocodingActivity) -> GoogleMapsActivity-> GoogleMapsFragment`

**FUNCTIONALITY**

The use of the app is simple. When I click on the Map button, it starts googleMaps. There, I click on any position of the map and it must return that position's coordinates to the main Activity and show them in the edittexts.

**CODE**

This is the code I use to start GoogleMaps:

```
/**ON BUTTON CLICK IN MAIN ACTIVITY*/
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(GeocodingActivity.this, GoogleMapsActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_MAP_LOCATION);

/**IN GOOGLEMAPSACTIVITY'S ONCREATE METHOD*/
GoogleMapsFragment mapsFragment = new GoogleMapsFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(android.R.id.content, mapsFragment).commit();
```

To send the data back from GoogleMapsFragment to mainActivity:

```
/**ON MAP LONG CLICK STARTS RETURNMAPDATA METHOD*/
mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
        mLatLng = arg0;
        ReturnMapData(mLatLng);
     }
});

/**METHOD THAT RETURNS DATA FORM GOOGLEMAPSFRAGMENT TO MAINACTIVITY*/
public void ReturnMapData(LatLng arg) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("maps_location", arg);
    intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
    getActivity().setResult(getActivity().RESULT_OK, intent);
}
```

And ant last to receive the data in the MainAcitivty with the onActivityResult method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_MAP_LOCATION) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Bundle bundle = data.getBundleExtra("bundle");
                LatLng coordinates = bundle.getParcelable("maps_location");
                mLocation.setLatitude(coordinates.latitude);
                mLocation.setLongitude(coordinates.longitude);
        }
    }
}
```

**ISSUE**

It seems to be all OK, but this is what I get on the LogCat. This happens in the onActivityResult method.

```
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.uax_final.reversegeocoding/.GoogleMapsActivity (has extras) }} to activity {com.uax_final.reversegeocoding/com.uax_final.reversegeocoding.GeocodingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3500)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3543)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:159)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at com.uax_final.reversegeocoding.GeocodingActivity.onActivityResult(GeocodingActivity.java:232)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563)
02-06 09:26:43.210: E/AndroidRuntime(20541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3496)
```

**UPDATE 1 -- POSIBLE REASON FOR THIS**

I've seen that the problem is that when returning the data from GoogleMapsFragment to the mainActivity the objects are null, and I think that this is because of the structure I use.

`MainActivity(GeocodingActivity) -> GoogleMapsActivity-> GoogleMapsFragment`

When I pass the data back from  GoogleMapsFragment to MainActivity, the activity openend is still GoogleMapsActivity, and this is the reason why this occurs.

Now, the thing is... how do I close GoogleMapsActivity when I have requested the data in GoogleMapsFragment and I want to get back to mainActivity???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself:

The problem is in the onActivityResult method.

The mLocation object is null so I can't use setLatitude and setLongitude methods.

The right way to do it would be this:

```
Location position = new Location("Test");
position.setLatitude(coordinates.latitude);
position.setLongitude(coordinates.longitude);
mLocation = position;
```